# C++ sorting and keeping track of indexes

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, indexing

Using C++, and hopefully the standard library, I want to sort a sequence of samples in ascending order, but I also want to remember the original indexes of the new samples.

For example, I have a set, or vector, or matrix of samples `A : [5, 2, 1, 4, 3]`. I want to sort these to be  `B : [1,2,3,4,5]`, but I also want to remember the original indexes of the values, so I can get another set which would be:
`C : [2, 1, 4, 3, 0 ]` - which corresponds to the index of each element in 'B', in the original 'A'.

For example, in Matlab you can do:

```
 [a,b]=sort([5, 8, 7])
 a = 5 7 8
 b = 1 3 2
```

Can anyone see a good way to do this?

Answer (score 384):

Using `C++` 11 lambdas:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>      // std::iota
#include <algorithm>    // std::sort, std::stable_sort

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
vector<size_t> sort_indexes(const vector<T> &v) {

  // initialize original index locations
  vector<size_t> idx(v.size());
  iota(idx.begin(), idx.end(), 0);

  // sort indexes based on comparing values in v
  // using std::stable_sort instead of std::sort
  // to avoid unnecessary index re-orderings
  // when v contains elements of equal values 
  stable_sort(idx.begin(), idx.end(),
       [&v](size_t i1, size_t i2) {return v[i1] < v[i2];});

  return idx;
}
```

Now you can use the returned index vector in iterations such as

```
for (auto i: sort_indexes(v)) {
  cout << v[i] << endl;
}
```

You can also choose to supply your original index vector, sort function, comparator, or automatically reorder v in the sort_indexes function using an extra vector.

Comment: Love this answer.If your compiler does not support lambdas, you can use a class:

template<typename T>
    class CompareIndicesByAnotherVectorValues
    {
      std::vector<T>* _values;
    public:
      CompareIndicesByAnotherVectorValues(std::vector<T>* values)
      : _values(values) {}
    public:
      bool operator() (const int& a, const int& b) const
      {
        return (*_values)[a] > (*_values)[b];
      }
    };

Comment: I love this answer too, there is no need to copy the original vector to create the vector of pairs.

Comment: This is much better than the accepted answer in my opinion! Awesome!

Comment: Rather than the hand-crafted `for (size_t i = 0; i != idx.size(); ++i) idx[i] = i;` I prefer the standard `std::iota( idx.begin(), idx.end(), 0 );`

Comment: use ```#include <numeric>``` for iota()

Comment: `iota` is the least obviously named algorithm in the entire C++ standard library.

Comment: @SethJohnson: I agree. IOTA stands for the 9th greek letter and then there is a crypto currency. That's on my mind when reading this.

Comment: Isn't `std::sort` faster than `std::stable_sort`? What are you gaining by using stable sort?

Comment: @simplename I don't know the reason for stable_sort, the edit was made and approved by others without justification. My guess is that due to the idx vector indirection on lookup, a stable sort would be more cache friendly?

Answer (score 91):

You could sort std::pair instead of just ints - first int is original data, second int is original index. Then supply a comparator that only sorts on the first int. Example:

```
Your problem instance: v = [5 7 8]
New problem instance: v_prime = [<5,0>, <8,1>, <7,2>]
```

Sort the new problem instance using a comparator like:

```
typedef std::pair<int,int> mypair;
bool comparator ( const mypair& l, const mypair& r)
   { return l.first < r.first; }
// forgetting the syntax here but intent is clear enough
```

The result of std::sort on v_prime, using that comparator, should be:

```
v_prime = [<5,0>, <7,2>, <8,1>]
```

You can peel out the indices by walking the vector, grabbing .second from each std::pair.

Comment: This is exactly how I would do it as well. The basic sort function doesn't track the old versus new positions as that would add extra unnecessary overhead.

Comment: The drawback with this function is that it requires you to reallocate memory for all values.

Comment: This is obviously a workable approach, but it has a downside that you have to change your original container from "container of numbers" to "container of pairs".

Answer (score 56):

Suppose Given vector is

```
A=[2,4,3]
```

Create a new vector

```
V=[0,1,2] // indicating positions
```

Sort V and while sorting instead of comparing elements of V , compare corresponding elements of A

```
 //Assume A is a given vector with N elements
 vector<int> V(N);
 std::iota(V.begin(),V.end(),0); //Initializing
 sort( V.begin(),V.end(), [&](int i,int j){return A[i]<A[j];} );
```

Answer (score 15):

```
vector<pair<int,int> >a;

for (i = 0 ;i < n ; i++) {
    // filling the original array
    cin >> k;
    a.push_back (make_pair (k,i)); // k = value, i = original index
}

sort (a.begin(),a.end());

for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
    cout << a[i].first << " " << a[i].second << "\n";
}
```

Now `a` contains both both our values and their respective indices in the sorted.

`a[i].first = value` at `i`'th.

`a[i].second = idx` in initial array.

Comment: Consider adding description of your code so that users that visit this post can understand __how__ it works.

Comment: I actually like this solution best - my vector is of size 4 or so and I'm stuck before C++11 and can't use lambdas. Thanks Aditya Aswal.

Answer (score 12):

I wrote generic version of index sort.

```
template <class RAIter, class Compare>
void argsort(RAIter iterBegin, RAIter iterEnd, Compare comp, 
    std::vector<size_t>& indexes) {

    std::vector< std::pair<size_t,RAIter> > pv ;
    pv.reserve(iterEnd - iterBegin) ;

    RAIter iter ;
    size_t k ;
    for (iter = iterBegin, k = 0 ; iter != iterEnd ; iter++, k++) {
        pv.push_back( std::pair<int,RAIter>(k,iter) ) ;
    }

    std::sort(pv.begin(), pv.end(), 
        [&comp](const std::pair<size_t,RAIter>& a, const std::pair<size_t,RAIter>& b) -> bool 
        { return comp(*a.second, *b.second) ; }) ;

    indexes.resize(pv.size()) ;
    std::transform(pv.begin(), pv.end(), indexes.begin(), 
        [](const std::pair<size_t,RAIter>& a) -> size_t { return a.first ; }) ;
}
```

Usage is the same as that of std::sort except for an index container to receive sorted indexes.
testing:

```
int a[] = { 3, 1, 0, 4 } ;
std::vector<size_t> indexes ;
argsort(a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]), std::less<int>(), indexes) ;
for (size_t i : indexes) printf("%d\n", int(i)) ;
```

you should get 2 1 0 3.
for the compilers without c++0x support, replace the lamba expression as a class template:

```
template <class RAIter, class Compare> 
class PairComp {
public:
  Compare comp ;
  PairComp(Compare comp_) : comp(comp_) {}
  bool operator() (const std::pair<size_t,RAIter>& a, 
    const std::pair<size_t,RAIter>& b) const { return comp(*a.second, *b.second) ; }        
} ;
```

and rewrite std::sort as

```
std::sort(pv.begin(), pv.end(), PairComp(comp)()) ;
```

Comment: Hi hkyi!   How do we instantiate this template function?  It has two template typename and one of them is a iterator which make this situation very rare.  Could you help?

Answer (score 6):

I came across this question, and figured out sorting the iterators directly would be a way to sort the values and keep track of indices; There is no need to define an extra container of `pair`s of ( value, index ) which is helpful when the values are large objects; The iterators provides the access to both the value and the index:

```
/*
 * a function object that allows to compare
 * the iterators by the value they point to
 */
template < class RAIter, class Compare >
class IterSortComp
{
    public:
        IterSortComp ( Compare comp ): m_comp ( comp ) { }
        inline bool operator( ) ( const RAIter & i, const RAIter & j ) const
        {
            return m_comp ( * i, * j );
        }
    private:
        const Compare m_comp;
};

template <class INIter, class RAIter, class Compare>
void itersort ( INIter first, INIter last, std::vector < RAIter > & idx, Compare comp )
{ 
    idx.resize ( std::distance ( first, last ) );
    for ( typename std::vector < RAIter >::iterator j = idx.begin( ); first != last; ++ j, ++ first )
        * j = first;

    std::sort ( idx.begin( ), idx.end( ), IterSortComp< RAIter, Compare > ( comp ) );
}
```

as for the usage example:

```
std::vector < int > A ( n );

// populate A with some random values
std::generate ( A.begin( ), A.end( ), rand );

std::vector < std::vector < int >::const_iterator > idx;
itersort ( A.begin( ), A.end( ), idx, std::less < int > ( ) );
```

now, for example, the 5th smallest element in the sorted vector would have value `**idx[ 5 ]` and its index in the original vector would be `distance( A.begin( ), *idx[ 5 ] )` or simply `*idx[ 5 ] - A.begin( )`.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using `std::multimap` as suggested by @Ulrich Eckhardt. Just that the code could be made even simpler.

Given

```
std::vector<int> a = {5, 2, 1, 4, 3};  // a: 5 2 1 4 3
```

To sort in the mean time of insertion

```
std::multimap<int, std::size_t> mm;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != a.size(); ++i)
    mm.insert({a[i], i});
```

To retrieve values and original indices

```
std::vector<int> b;
std::vector<std::size_t> c;
for (const auto & kv : mm) {
    b.push_back(kv.first);             // b: 1 2 3 4 5
    c.push_back(kv.second);            // c: 2 1 4 3 0
}
```

*The reason to prefer a `std::multimap` to a `std::map` is to allow equal values in original vectors. Also please note that, unlike for `std::map`, `operator[]` is not defined for `std::multimap`.*

Answer (score 3):

There is another way to solve this, using a map:

```
vector<double> v = {...}; // input data
map<double, unsigned> m; // mapping from value to its index
for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    m[*it] = it - v.begin();
```

This will eradicate non-unique elements though. If that's not acceptable, use a multimap:

```
vector<double> v = {...}; // input data
multimap<double, unsigned> m; // mapping from value to its index
for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    m.insert(make_pair(*it, it - v.begin()));
```

In order to output the indices, iterate over the map or multimap:

```
for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
    cout << it->second << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

Beautiful solution by @Lukasz Wiklendt! Although in my case I needed something more generic so I modified it a bit:

```
template <class RAIter, class Compare>
vector<size_t> argSort(RAIter first, RAIter last, Compare comp) {

  vector<size_t> idx(last-first);
  iota(idx.begin(), idx.end(), 0);

  auto idxComp = [&first,comp](size_t i1, size_t i2) {
      return comp(first[i1], first[i2]);
  };

  sort(idx.begin(), idx.end(), idxComp);

  return idx;
}
```

Example: Find indices sorting a vector of strings by length, except for the first element which is a dummy.

```
vector<string> test = {"dummy", "a", "abc", "ab"};

auto comp = [](const string &a, const string& b) {
    return a.length() > b.length();
};

const auto& beginIt = test.begin() + 1;
vector<size_t> ind = argSort(beginIt, test.end(), comp);

for(auto i : ind)
    cout << beginIt[i] << endl;
```

prints:

```
abc
ab
a
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a `std::pair` in function then sort pair :

generic version :

```
template< class RandomAccessIterator,class Compare >
auto sort2(RandomAccessIterator begin,RandomAccessIterator end,Compare cmp) ->
   std::vector<std::pair<std::uint32_t,RandomAccessIterator>>
{
    using valueType=typename std::iterator_traits<RandomAccessIterator>::value_type;
    using Pair=std::pair<std::uint32_t,RandomAccessIterator>;

    std::vector<Pair> index_pair;
    index_pair.reserve(std::distance(begin,end));

    for(uint32_t idx=0;begin!=end;++begin,++idx){
        index_pair.push_back(Pair(idx,begin));
    }

    std::sort( index_pair.begin(),index_pair.end(),[&](const Pair& lhs,const Pair& rhs){
          return cmp(*lhs.second,*rhs.second);
    });

    return index_pair;
}
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/zCLx2W)

Answer (score 2):

I recently stepped upon the elegant **projection** feature of C++20 `<ranges>` and it allows to write shorter/clearer code:

```
std::vector<std::size_t> B(std::size(A));
std::iota(begin(B), end(B), 0);
std::ranges::sort(B, {}, [&](std::size_t i){ return A[i]; });
```

`{}` refers to the usual `std::less<std::size_t>`. So as you can see we define a function to call on each element before any comparaison. This projection feature is actually quite powerful since this function can be, as here, a lambda or it can even be a method, or a member value. For instance:

```
struct Item {
    float price;
    float weight;
    float efficiency() const { return price / weight; }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Item> items{{7, 9}, {3, 4}, {5, 3}, {9, 7}};
    std::ranges::sort(items, std::greater<>(), &Item::efficiency);
    // now items are sorted by their efficiency in decreasing order:
    // items = {{5, 3}, {9, 7}, {7, 9}, {3, 4}}
}
```

If we wanted to sort by increasing price:

```
std::ranges::sort(items, {}, &Item::price);
```

Don't define `operator<` or use lambdas, use a projection!

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible, you can build the position array using find function, and then sort the array.

Or maybe you can use a map where the key would be the element, and the values a list of its position in the upcoming arrays (A, B and C)

It depends on later uses of those arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my solution uses residue technique. We can place the values under sorting in the upper 2 bytes and the indices of the elements - in the lower 2 bytes:

```
int myints[] = {32,71,12,45,26,80,53,33};

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
   myints[i] = myints[i]*(1 << 16) + i;
```

Then sort the array `myints` as usual:

```
std::vector<int> myvector(myints, myints+8);
sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.begin()+8, std::less<int>());
```

After that you can access the elements' indices via residuum. The following code prints the indices of the values sorted in the ascending order:

```
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = myvector.begin(); it != myvector.end(); ++it)
   std::cout << ' ' << (*it)%(1 << 16);
```

Of course, this technique works only for the relatively small values in the original array `myints` (i.e. those which can fit into upper 2 bytes of `int`). But it has additional benefit of distinguishing identical values of `myints`: their indices will be printed in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

Are the items in the vector unique? If so, copy the vector, sort one of the copies with [STL Sort](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/sort.html) then you can find which index each item had in the original vector.

If the vector is supposed to handle duplicate items, I think youre better of implementing your own sort routine.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of question
Store the orignal array data into a new data and then binary search the first element of the sorted array into the duplicated array and that indice should be stored into a vector or array.

```
input array=>a
duplicate array=>b
vector=>c(Stores the indices(position) of the orignal array
Syntax:
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
c.push_back(binarysearch(b,n,a[i]));`
```

Here binarysearch is a function which takes the array,size of array,searching item and would return the position of the searched item

Answer (score -2):

One solution is to use a 2D vector.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 vector<vector<double>> val_and_id;
 val_and_id.resize(5);
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   val_and_id[i].resize(2); // one to store value, the other for index.
 }
 // Store value in dimension 1, and index in the other:
 // say values are 5,4,7,1,3.
 val_and_id[0][0] = 5.0;
 val_and_id[1][0] = 4.0;
 val_and_id[2][0] = 7.0;
 val_and_id[3][0] = 1.0;
 val_and_id[4][0] = 3.0;

 val_and_id[0][1] = 0.0;
 val_and_id[1][1] = 1.0;
 val_and_id[2][1] = 2.0;
 val_and_id[3][1] = 3.0;
 val_and_id[4][1] = 4.0;

 sort(val_and_id.begin(), val_and_id.end());
 // display them:
 cout << "Index \t" << "Value \n";
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  cout << val_and_id[i][1] << "\t" << val_and_id[i][0] << "\n";
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
   Index   Value
   3       1
   4       3
   1       4
   0       5
   2       7
```