# sort one array and other array following?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

here is the C++ sample

```
int a[1000] = {3,1,5,4}
int b[1000] = {7,9,11,3}
```

how do i make it so if i sort array a, array b also following array a

example

```
a[1000] = {1,3,4,5}
b[1000] = {9,7,3,11}
```

is it possible using sort function

```
sort(a,a+4)
```

but also sort array b aswell ?

edit: what if there are 3 arrays ?

Comment: you sort with an index.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577475/c-sorting-and-keeping-track-of-indexes

Comment: @ben because b isn't sorted. it's re-arranged in the same way as a was.

Comment: Aha. Then zuelb ought to write his own sort function.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using two arrays, can you use an array of `pair`s and then sort THAT using a special comparison functor rather than the default less-than operator?

Comment: what if there is 3 arrays, is it possible to use this method ?

Comment: Well you need a 3-tuple in that case (or write yourself a struct for it), but basically, sure.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to rearrange your data into an array-of-structs instead of a pair of arrays so that each datum is contiguous; then, you can use an appropriate comparator.  For example:

```
struct CompareFirst
{
    bool operator() (const std::pair<int,int>& lhs, const std::pair<int,int>& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.first < rhs.first;
    }
};

// c[i].first contains a[i], c[i].second contains b[i] for all i
std::pair<int, int> c[1000];
std::sort(c, c+1000, CompareFirst());
```

If you can't refactor your data like that, then you need to define a custom class that acts as a [RandomAccessIterator](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/RandomAccessIterator.html):

```
struct ParallalArraySortHelper
{
    ParallelArraySortHelper(int *first, int *second)
        : a(first), b(second)
    {
    }

    int& operator[] (int index) { return a[index]; }
    int operator[] const (int index) { return a[index]; }

    ParallelArraySortHelper operator += (int distance)
    {
        a += distance;
        b += distance;
        return *this;
    }
    // etc.
    // Rest of the RandomAccessIterator requirements left as an exercise

    int *a;
    int *b;
};
...
int a[1000] = {...};
int b[1000] = {...};
std::sort(ParallalArraySortHelper(a, b), ParallelArraySortHelper(a+1000, b+1000));
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate an array the same size as the original, containing the indexes into the array: `{0, 1, 2, 3}`. Now use a custom comparator functor that compares the elements in an associated array rather than the indexes themselves.

```
template<typename T>
class CompareIndices
{
public:
    CompareIndices(const T * array) : m_AssociatedArray(array) {}
    bool operator() (int left, int right) const
    {
        return std::less(m_AssociatedArray[left], m_AssociatedArray[right]);
    }
private:
    const T * m_AssociatedArray;
};

std::sort(i, i+4, CompareIndices(a));
```

Once you have a sorted list of indices, you can apply it to the original array `a`, or any other `b` array you want.