# Rcpp: rearrange a vector in an order of another vector

Tags: c++, r, sorting, rcpp

I am new in Rcpp. I need to rearrange a vector `A` in an order of another vector `B`;
For example,

```
A=c(0.5,0.4,0.2,0.9)
B=c(9,1,3,5)
```

I want to make `C=c(0.4,0.2,0.9,0.5)` by Rcpp.

I know the simple r code, `C=A[order(B)]`, but it is necessary for me to use Rcpp code.

I found how to find the order of `B` by using `sort_index`, but I fail to arrange `A` with respect to an order of `B`.

How can I make it?

Comment: See http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/top-elements-from-vectors-using-priority-queue/ and https://github.com/hadley/adv-r/blob/master/extras/cpp/order.cpp

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to use `arma::sort_index` for this, which you mention in your post:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec arma_sort(arma::vec x, arma::vec y) {
    return x(arma::sort_index(y));
}

/*** R
A <- c(0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.9)
B <- c(9, 1, 3, 5)
arma_sort(A, B)
*/
```

Result:

```
> arma_sort(A, B)
     [,1]
[1,]  0.4
[2,]  0.2
[3,]  0.9
[4,]  0.5
```

Of course, there are other ways as well. Variations on this question have been asked a few times on Stack Overflow in the context of plain C++. Below I've adapted the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25921907/8386140) for Rcpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector Rcpp_sort(NumericVector x, NumericVector y) {
    // Order the elements of x by sorting y
    // First create a vector of indices
    IntegerVector idx = seq_along(x) - 1;
    // Then sort that vector by the values of y
    std::sort(idx.begin(), idx.end(), [&](int i, int j){return y[i] < y[j];});
    // And return x in that order
    return x[idx];
}

/*** R
A <- c(0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.9)
B <- c(9, 1, 3, 5)
Rcpp_sort(A, B)
*/
```

Result:

```
> Rcpp_sort(A, B)
[1] 0.4 0.2 0.9 0.5
```