# Armadillo C++: Sorting a vector in terms of two other vectors

Tags: c++, r, vector, rcpp, armadillo

My question relates to a sorting exercise, which I can undertake easily (but perhaps slowly) in R and would like to undertake in C++ in order to speed up my code.

Consider three vectors of the same size a,b and c. In R, the following command would sort the vector first in terms of b and then, in case of ties, would further sort in terms of c.

```
a<-a[order(b,c),1]
```

Example:

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
b<-c(1,2,1,2,1)
c<-c(5,4,3,2,1)

> a[order(b,c)]
[1] 5 3 1 4 2
```

Is there an efficient way to undertake this in C++ using Armadillo vectors?

Comment: Should be fast enough in R.

Comment: This question might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48118248/rcpp-rearrange-a-vector-in-an-order-of-another-vector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can write the following C++ solution, which I have in a file `SO_answer.cpp`:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
vec arma_sort(vec x, vec y, vec z) {
    // Order the elements of x by sorting y and z;
    // we order by y unless there's a tie, then order by z.
    // First create a vector of indices
    uvec idx = regspace<uvec>(0, x.size() - 1);
    // Then sort that vector by the values of y and z
    std::sort(idx.begin(), idx.end(), [&](int i, int j){
        if ( y[i] == y[j] ) {
            return z[i] < z[j];
        }
        return y[i] < y[j];
    });
    // And return x in that order
    return x(idx);
}
```

What we've done is take advantage of the fact that `std::sort()` allows you to sort based on a custom comparator. We use a comparator that compares the elements of `z` only if the elements of `y` are equal; otherwise it compares the values of `y`.<sup>1</sup> Then we can compile the file and test the function in R:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("SO_answer.cpp")

set.seed(1234)
x <- sample(1:10)
y <- sample(1:10)
z <- sample(1:10)

y[sample(1:10, 1)] <- 1 # create a tie

all.equal(x[order(y, z)], c(arma_sort(x, y, z))) # check against R
# [1] TRUE # Good
```

Of course, we must also consider whether this actually gives you any performance increase, which is the whole reason why you're doing this. Let's benchmark:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(r = x[order(y, z)],
               arma = arma_sort(x, y, z),
               times = 1e4)

Unit: microseconds
 expr    min    lq      mean median    uq      max neval cld
    r 36.040 37.23 39.386160  37.64 38.32 3316.286 10000   b
 arma  5.055  6.07  7.155676   7.00  7.53  107.230 10000  a
```

On my machine, it looks like you get about a 5-6X increase in speed with small vectors, though this advantage doesn't hold as well when you scale up:

```
x <- sample(1:100)
y <- sample(1:100)
z <- sample(1:100)

y[sample(1:100, 10)] <- 1 # create some ties

all.equal(x[order(y, z)], c(arma_sort(x, y, z))) # check against R
# [1] TRUE # Good

microbenchmark(r = x[order(y, z)],
               arma = arma_sort(x, y, z),
               times = 1e4)

Unit: microseconds
 expr   min     lq     mean median     uq      max neval cld
    r 44.50 46.360 48.01275 46.930 47.755  294.051 10000   b
 arma 10.76 12.045 16.30033 13.015 13.715 5262.132 10000  a 

x <- sample(1:1000)
y <- sample(1:1000)
z <- sample(1:1000)

y[sample(1:100, 10)] <- 1 # create some ties

all.equal(x[order(y, z)], c(arma_sort(x, y, z))) # check against R
# [1] TRUE # Good

microbenchmark(r = x[order(y, z)],
               arma = arma_sort(x, y, z),
               times = 1e4)

Unit: microseconds
 expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
    r 113.765 118.7950 125.7387 120.5075 122.4475 3373.696 10000   b
 arma  82.690  91.3925 104.0755  95.2350  99.4325 6040.162 10000  a
```

It's still faster, but by less than 2X once you're at vectors of length 1000. This is probably why [F. Privé](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6103040/f-priv%c3%a9) said this operation should be fast enough in R. While moving to C++ using Rcpp can give you great performance advantages, the extent to which you get gains is largely dependent on context, as mentioned many times by [Dirk Eddelbuettel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel) in answers to various questions here.

---

1 <sub>Note that typically for sorting Armadillo vectors I would suggest using `sort()` or `sort_index()` (see the Armadillo docs [here](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#sort_index)). If you're trying to sort a `vec` by the values of a second `vec`, you could use`x(arma::sort_index(y))` as I indicated in an answer to a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48121529/8386140). You can even use `stable_sort_index()` to preserve ties. However, I couldn't figure out how to use these functions to solve the specific problem you present here.</sub>

Comment: Nice answer. I also didn't see how to make the existing Armadillo routines respect more than one pair of vectors.

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel! Yeah, if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/blob/unstable/include/armadillo_bits/op_sort_meat.hpp), you can see there is no way to pass a custom comparator to Armadillo sort functions, but you can also see they just call `std::sort()`, so I figured this approach was good enough.

Comment: Thanks @duckmayr ! After some thinking, another solution lies in the fact that you can always define a new vector d in such a way that it provides the same ranking as b except when ties occur, in which wase you make the ranking provided by c kick in. Still your solution is way neater.