# C++ sorting a vector of structs

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, struct, stl

I am new to C++ and am trying to sort a vector based on values in another vector. I am trying to implement this by creating a vector of structs and sorting the vector of stucts using the STL. The structs have 2 data items, one a CustomType and the other an int. I want this sorted in decreasing order of the int field, and have therefore included a boolean operator overloading to be able to use the STL sort (algorithm).

The struct is constructed in the function using references to the CustomType vector and an initially uninitialised int vector, and combining them into a vector of structs. The values for the ints are obtained by calling a separate member function of SomeClass (SomeFunc) on each item of the CustomType vector and another u_int8_t param (this function works fine by itself).

In the end, I want to replace the sorted CustomType objects based on the sorted struct sequence.

The implementation file (.cpp) has the following function:

```
void SomeClass::orderFunc(std::vector<CustomType>& x, std::vector<int>& y, u_int8_t param){
    std::vector<CustomStruct> xy_vec;
    y.assign(x.size(), 0);   
    int count  = int(x.size());
    
    for(int i=0; i != count; ++i){
        y[i] = SomeFunc(x[i], param);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i != count; ++i){
        xy_vec[i].var1 = x[i];
        xy_vec[i].var2 = y[i];
    }
    std::sort(xy_vec.begin(), xy_vec.end()); 
    for(int i = 0; i != count; ++i){
        x[i] = xy_vec[i].var2;
    }
}
```

The struct is defined in the SomeClass header file as below:

```
struct CustomStruct{
        CustomType var1;
        int var2;
        bool operator>(const CustomStruct& a) const{
            return (this->var2 > a.var2);
        }
    };
```

When this function is called,  I get the following error:

> invalid operands to binary expression
>
> bool operator()(const _T1& __x, const _T1& __y) const {return __x < __y;}

I can't understand why the bool operator overloading is invalid given that this is being defined for the int field of the struct.

What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated. Also, any suggestions for a more elegant way to do this would be great as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921706/creating-a-vector-of-indices-of-a-sorted-vector or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580982/c-sort-keeping-track-of-indices

Answer (score 2):

You need to overload **`operator<`** and not `operator>`

```
bool operator<(const CustomStruct& a) const
{
    return (this->var2 < a.var2);
}
```

**EDIT:** For sorting in reverse order, you need to call `std::sort` with `rbegin()` and `rend()` (reverse) iterators:

```
std::sort(xy_vec.rbegin(), xy_vec.rend());
```

**EDIT** (again, as the question is too long, has 2 problems):

The vector `xy_vec` is empty, you need to call `resize`:

```
std::vector<CustomStruct> xy_vec;
// Resize here
xy_vec.resize(count);
for(int i = 0; i != count; ++i){
    xy_vec[i].var1 = x[i];
    xy_vec[i].var2 = y[i];
```

Or you can call `push_back` - I am not telling you all that. Please find!

Comment: I mention that I need it sorted in decreasing order. Isn't > the operator to overload for that? Also, overloading the < operator gives me a seg fault, I have no idea why.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Your question has a lot of text, and that's why I didn't read it fully. You should ask complete but concise questions.

Comment: Overloading < and using rbegin and rend gives me a seg fault.

Comment: Please read the updated answer. And please ask good question to receive good response!

Answer (score 2):

`std::sort` has two main overloads, one without a sort predicate that defaults to using `operator <` and one with a sort predicate (details [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)).

So you could write something like

```
struct CustomStructCmp {
    bool operator()(const CustomStruct& a, const CustomStruct& b) const
    {   
        return a.var2 > b.var2;
    }   
};

std::sort(xy_vec.begin(), xy_vec.end(), CustomStructCmp());
```

(if you are using C++11 then you could use a lambda instead).

Alternatively you could write

```
std::sort(xy_vec.begin(), xy_vec.end(), std::greater<CustomStruct>());
```

but I feel that it is more natural to directly use a functor/lambda rather than define `operator>` and use the `std::greater` functor.