# sort a list and return their original order or subscript

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, quicksort

Hi I am using Qt to writing a function, in which the following action would be done:

1) sort a qlist<double>;

2) return the subscript of each element with the same order of qlist<double>  or return each element's original order

For example:

Original qlist: 2.3, 1.8, 4.5, 3.6
Return value: 1, 0, 3, 2   (Because the qlist was: 1.8, 2.3, 3.6, 4.5 after sorting)

Based on quick sort, I have wrote one as follows, but the speed was very slow. The time cost was about:

10,000 takes 13.9168

100,000 takes 120.387 secs

Could you give me some advice to optimize this code? Thanks In advance.

```
#include <QString>
#include <QVector>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTime>
#include "sys/time.h"


void subArrayQuickSort(QList<double> * targetArray, QVector <qint64> * subArray, qint64 min, qint64 max);

int main(){
    QList<double> pvalue;
    QVector<qint64> subscript;
    qint64 totalNumber = 10000;

    struct timeval tpstart,tpend;
    for(qint64 i =0; i< totalNumber; i++){
        qsrand((uint)QTime::currentTime().msec());
        double tmpNumber = 1.0 * ( qrand() % 100000 /100000 ) ;

        pvalue.append(tmpNumber);
        subscript.append(i);
    }

    qDebug() << "sort start ...";
    gettimeofday(&tpstart,NULL);
    subArrayQuickSort(&pvalue,&subscript,0,totalNumber-1);

    gettimeofday(&tpend,NULL);
    qDebug() << "time cost:" << (1000000*(tpend.tv_sec-tpstart.tv_sec) + tpend.tv_usec-tpstart.tv_usec)/1000000.0;

    return 0;

}

// sort the subscript of the array desc
void subArrayQuickSort(QList<double> * targetArray, QVector <qint64> * subArray, qint64 min, qint64 max){
    if(min>=max){
        return;
    }
    qint64 first = min;
    qint64 last = max;
    qint64 refSub = subArray->at(first);
    double refSubValue = targetArray->at(refSub);
    while (first < last) {
        while (first < last && targetArray->at(subArray->at(last)) <= refSubValue ) {
            last--;
        }
        subArray->replace(first,subArray->at(last));

        while (first < last && targetArray->at(subArray->at(first)) >= refSubValue ) {
            first++;
        }
        subArray->replace(last,subArray->at(first));
    }
    subArray->replace(first,refSub);
    subArrayQuickSort(targetArray,subArray,min,first - 1);
    subArrayQuickSort(targetArray,subArray,first + 1, max);
}
```

Comment: your time complexity looks optimal. (usual high-level aproach is: pair up each element in the input list with increasing index [0,1,2,3...]; sort by custom routine comparing the first values of each pair; create new list containing second value of each pair in the sorted list.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task is to sort which keeping track of indexes. Using "sort" provided by C++ STL algorithm will be better than creating your own wheel. One possible solution is here: [C++ sorting and keeping track of indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577475/c-sorting-and-keeping-track-of-indexes).

To take fully advantage of C++11 lambda in QT, enter

> CONFIG += c++11

in your .pro file.

There are several tricks in quick sort that can slow your code down. A better implementation of quick sort can refer to "Column 11: Sorting" in book "Programming Peals, Second Edition".