# Sort Array of Indexes Into Primary Array

Tags: c++, sorting, lambda, import-from-excel, safearray

I'm coding a C++ dll to sort a SAFEARRAY passed from VBA.

I'm not using any OLE libraries, but rather accessing the array descriptor and data directly.

I have no problem sorting an array of any native VBA types. For example, the following fragment sorts an array of BSTRs:

```
long * p = (long*)pData; 

std::sort(p, p + elems, comparestring);
```

...which uses this comparison function:

```
bool comparestring(const long& lhs, const long& rhs) {

   wchar_t * lhs_ = (wchar_t*)lhs;
   wchar_t * rhs_ = (wchar_t*)rhs;

   return _wcsicmp(lhs_, rhs_) < 0;
}
```

I realize I'm cheating here since `wchar_t` is very different from `BSTR`, but it's not common to have a zero char within the payload of an Excel string and so I'm OK with that. The above works well.

**THE PROBLEM**

I want the dll to optionally be able to sort a companion array of indexes into the primary data array. In this mode only the index array would be sorted, leaving the source data untouched.

My research suggests that a lamda functor may be the most promising path as I'd prefer not to allocate memory for additional arrays or vectors of data or pairs.

In particular, [this answer seems very promising](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12399290/3566998).

However, I cannot work out how to adapt it to my situation where I'm processing the raw pointers to the BSTRs that begin at pData.

I have tried the following:

```
long * p = (long*)pData; 

long ndx[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) ndx[i] = i + 1;

std::sort(ndx[0], ndx[4], [&p](long i1, long i2) { comparestring((*p) + i1, (*p) + i2); })
```

I am using VC++ 2015 and the above results in the following error:

`Error  C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'iterator_traits<_Iter>::iterator_category std::_Iter_cat(const _Iter &)'`

My C programming days are ancient history (predating the existence of C++) and so I'm struggling a little. Appreciate any assistance.

**UPDATE**

The code now looks like this.. and it compiles, but the order of `ndx` is incorrect after execution:

```
long * p = (long*)pData; 

long ndx[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) ndx[i] = i + 1;

std::sort(ndx, ndx + 5, [&p](long i1, long i2) { return comparestring(*p + i1, *p + i2); })
```

Comment: The lambda needs to return a boolean value (e.g. `return comparestring.....`

Comment: also you probably meant `ndx, ndx + 5` instead of `ndx[0], ndx[4]`. That should make it compile but it seems to me that your pointer cast hackery is still producing junk

Comment: Thanks. I tried using place the three statements from inside `comparestring` directly into the lambda, and even though it would then return a boolean, I got the exact same error.

Comment: Does your compiler come with a C++ wrapper for SAFEARRAY? That would save a lot of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Yes, but this is for educational purposes. Using a wrapper obscures a lot of what is going on. The project has worked out very well so far. As mentioned, I can sort arrays of all the native types including VBA's Variant. I am surprised that extending this to sorting an array of indexes into the the SAFEARRAY is difficult.

Comment: Maybe drawing a memory map would help you. `(*p) + i1, (*p) + i2` is obviously wrong, as `i1` and `i2` are taking values from 1 through 5, but your `comparestring` function is expecting to get pointers to different strings to compare (when in fact it will get pointers to adjacent bytes)

Comment: By the way, `ndx, ndx + 5` does not compile either... but the errors are different. It now reports: `conditional expression of type 'void' is illegal`

Comment: Did you fix the missing `return` ?

Comment: Yes, and it does compile now. But, the returned sorted order of the indexes is wrong.

Comment: Yes, see my earlier comment about `i1`, `i2`

Comment: @M.M Can you suggest a link for me to read up on what you are talking about. it's literally been decades for me... or if you could post a code example?

Comment: Not really, I don't know of any documentation of safearray apart from what's on the MSDN website.

Comment: Just re-read you comment, but it seems to me that the pointer arithmetic should work. Yes the number coming from `i1` and `i2` will be the values 1 to 5, but the pData is sequential long pointers to the strings...

Comment: Have you considered using the Windows API functions for accessing the array members, instead of adding integers?

Comment: Your first test will be `comparestring(1000, 1001)` or similar, those clearly cannot point to different strings

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am good with my understanding of the the documentation of SAFEARRAY. I know it very well. C++ is my weakness. I did not get the memory map suggestion.

Comment: Since `*p` is a `long`, and if `p = 1000`, shouldn't `p + 1 = 1004` ?

Comment: Yes, but you're doing `*p`, not `p`. You're adding two integers.

Comment: @M.M I fixed it with your help... so thanks. I needed ndx to be populated starting with zero instead of one (doh!) and then this did the trick in the lambda:  `return comparestring(*(p + i1), *(p + i2));` Please write an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
long ndx[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) ndx[i] = i + 1;
std::sort(ndx[0], ndx[4], [&p](long i1, long i2) { comparestring((*p) + i1, (*p) + i2); })
```

should probably be:

```
long ndx[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) ndx[i] = i;
std::sort(ndx, ndx + 5, [&](long i1, long i2) { return comparestring(*(p + i1), *(p + i2)); }
```

The first two arguments to `std::sort` are an iterator range. It'd be better style (assuming your compiler is C++11-compatible) to use `std::begin(ndx)` and `std::end(ndx)`.

Also, the second line can be written `std::iota( std::begin(ndx), std::end(ndx), 0 );`