# C++ Armadillo: Get the ranks of the elements in a vector

Tags: c++, armadillo

Suppose I have a vector, and I want to get the ranks of the elements if they were sorted.

So if I have the vector:

```
0.5
1.5
3.5
0.1
```

and I need returned the ranks of each element:

```
2
3
4
1
```

Is there a way to do this in Armadillo? This is different than the previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577475/c-sorting-and-keeping-track-of-indexes) since we are getting the ranks and not the indices before sorting.

Comment: make a std::map<int,int>,  take a copy of your vector, sort it, attach the index of the key "every original number" as its value in the map, then iterate the original vector and get its value from the map

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ sorting and keeping track of indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577475/c-sorting-and-keeping-track-of-indexes)

Comment: @yuyoyuppe Not a duplicate

Comment: @Cauchy is [that](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#sort_index) what you're looking for?

Comment: @yuyoyuppe already tried that, doesn't do what i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, check this out:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector> // std:: vector
#include <algorithm> // std::sort
#include <map> // std::map

using namespace std;


int main() {
    vector<double> myVector = { 0.5, 1.5, 3.5, 0.1 };
    vector<double> Sorted = myVector;

    std::sort(Sorted.begin(), Sorted.end());

    map<double, int> myMap;

    for (int i = 0; i < Sorted.size() ; i++)
    {
        myMap.insert(make_pair(Sorted[i],i));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size() ; i++)
    {
        auto it = myMap.find(myVector[i]);
        cout << it->second + 1 << endl;
    }

    return 0;
};
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: How can you handle the repeated values?

Comment: @drbombe if you want all duplicate numbers to have the same rank, then you will need remove duplicate from the initial vector

Comment: But in that case, the largest rank will not be the same as the size of the vector right? I provided an alternative solution below. Please feel free to comment if it can be improved in complexity.

Comment: @drbombe Right, and I assume ranks do not have to be the same size as the vector. Since you have the `map`, then any value you access on the vector, can retrieve its rank (from the map)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my codes using STL to get the rankings in a concise way

```
template <typename T>
vector<size_t> calRank(const vector<T> & var) {
    vector<size_t> result(var.size());
    //sorted index
    vector<size_t> indx(var.size());
    iota(indx.begin(),indx.end(),0);
    sort(indx.begin(),indx.end(),[&var](int i1, int i2){return var[i1]<var[i2];});
    //return ranking
    for(size_t iter=0;iter<var.size();++iter){
        //it may cause overflow for a really long vector, in practice it should be ok.
        result[indx[iter]]=iter+1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in pure *Armadillo* code, using the function `arma::sort_index()`.

The function `arma::sort_index()` calculates the permutation index to sort a given vector into ascending order.

Applying the function `arma::sort_index()` twice:
`arma::sort_index(arma::sort_index())}`, calculates the *reverse* permutation index to sort the vector from ascending order back into its original unsorted order.  The ranks of the elements are equal to the *reverse* permutation index.

Below is *Armadillo* code wrapped in *RcppArmadillo* that defines the function `calc_ranks()`.   The function `calc_ranks()` calculates the ranks of the elements of a vector, and it can be called from *R*.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// Define the function calc_ranks(), to calculate 
// the ranks of the elements of a vector.
//
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::uvec calc_ranks(const arma::vec& da_ta) {
  return (arma::sort_index(arma::sort_index(da_ta)) + 1);
}  // end calc_ranks
```

The above code can be saved to the file *calc_ranks.cpp*, so it can be compiled in *R* using the function `Rcpp::sourceCpp()`.

Below is *R* code to test the function `calc_ranks()` (after it's been compiled in *R*):

```
# Compile Rcpp functions
Rcpp::sourceCpp(file="C:/Develop/R/Rcpp/calc_ranks.cpp")

# Create a vector of random data
da_ta <- runif(7)
# Calculate the ranks of the elements
calc_ranks(da_ta)

# Compare with the R function rank()
all.equal(rank(da_ta), drop(calc_ranks(da_ta)))
```