# Sort one vector using another in nonincreasing order

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14

This mean that while I am sorting the v2 in the nonincreasing order, the v1 should looks like this:

*Vectors look as following.*

```
v1  = {0, 5, 5, 2,  10};
v2  = {0 ,2, 6, 20, 5};
```

*The output:*

```
v1 = {2,  5, 10, 5, 0};
v2 = {20, 6,  5, 2, 0};
```

I was trying to solve that problem mixing `std::sort` and lambdas.
That is why I have read several questions about `std::sort`, there were no answers which solve the problem similar to mine so that is why I am  asking.

I am especially interested in the answers which contains it's usage or other features of C++11 and C++14.

**It is not a question like:**

*"I completely do not know what to do."*

I know how to achieve the output using C++98, but I am wondering if there is an more efficient and prettier way to do it.

Big thanks for your help :)

Comment: What does your C++98 code look like?

Comment: Your output v2 has one less element

Comment: Well I said that I know how to achieve it in C++98 I did not say that I got the code. The idea was to store indexes which are moved to sort v2 and using these indexes to sort v1.

Comment: Plus, the output is in non-increasing order, IMHO.

Comment: Convert from a pair of vectors to a vector of pairs, sort, convert back.

Comment: Googled "C++ argsort", and got this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577475/c-sorting-and-keeping-track-of-indexes

Comment: @LukeLee Thanks I do not know how could I miss the answer. Probably by the fact that English is not my national language.

Comment: can you provide a custom swap (via specialization or some other mechanism) that would be used by std::sort but which would swap _both_ arrays?  (I looked this up on other SO questions and still can't figure out how if there is a way to make this work...)

Comment: Read about tag sort, sort the second vector to get the indexes, then use the latter to re-arrange the first one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could `zip`, `sort`, and `unzip`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

//converts two vectors into vector of pairs
template <typename T, typename U>
auto zip(T t, U u) {
  std::vector<std::pair<typename T::value_type,typename U::value_type>> pairs;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < t.size(); ++i){
    pairs.emplace_back(u[i],t[i]);
  }
  return pairs;
}

//converts a vector of pairs, back into two two vectors
template <typename T, typename U, typename V>
void unzip(V pairs, T & t, U & u) {
  for (auto const& it: pairs){
    u.emplace_back(it.first);
    t.emplace_back(it.second);
  }
}


int main(){

  //vectors
  std::vector<int> v1  = {0, 5, 5, 2,  10};
  std::vector<int> v2  = {0 ,2, 6, 20, 5};

  //zip vectors
  auto pairs = zip(v1,v2);

  //sort them
  std::sort(pairs.begin(),pairs.end(),std::greater<>());

  //unzip them
  v1.clear();
  v2.clear();
  unzip(pairs,v1,v2);

  //print
  std::cout << '\n';
  for (auto i: v1) std::cout << i << ' ';
  std::cout << '\n';
  for (auto i: v2) std::cout << i << ' ';
  std::cout << '\n';

}
```

Comment: How does `std::greater<>()` work, without an explicit template argument? Does the `greater` template have a default argument that allows it to be more generic?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid void specialization from C++14.  The default type is void, and that deduces the arguments and return types.

Comment: Instead of physically zipping and unzipping two vectors, one can do it virtually by defining ZipIterator that traverses two vectors in parallel, with properly defined iterator operators.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't if this is would be efficient, or not, but this demonstrates how to do this with `std::generate`, `std::sort`, and `std::transform`, with some extra seasoning from mutable lambdas, and iterators.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1={0, 5, 5, 2,  10},
        v2  = {0, 2, 6, 20, 5};

    std::vector<int> index;

    index.resize(5);

    std::generate(index.begin(), index.end(),
              [n=0]
              ()
              mutable
              {
                  return n++;
              });

    std::sort(index.begin(), index.end(),
          [&]
          (auto &a, auto &b)
          {
              return v2[b] < v2[a];
          });

    std::vector<int> v1_out, v2_out;

    std::transform(index.begin(), index.end(),
               std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int>>(v1_out),
               [&]
               (auto a)
               {
                   return v1[a];
               });

    std::transform(index.begin(), index.end(),
               std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int>>(v2_out),
               [&]
               (auto a)
               {
                   return v2[a];
               });

    for (auto n: v1_out)
        std::cout << n << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (auto n: v2_out)
        std::cout << n << ' ';

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: instead of generate +  mutable lambda, std::iota from <numeric>

Comment: Thanks for your afford ;)

Comment: Interesting design, though I find `std::back_inserter` more readable than the raw `std::back_insert_iterator<SomeLongType>`.

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks for all your answers. I found an easy way to achieve the same effect and the idea comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12399290/6129691).

1.
Firstly I used all code from answer which I linked, so it is:

```
template <typename T>
vector<size_t> sort_indexes(const vector<T> &v)
{

  // initialize original index locations
  vector<size_t> idx(v.size());
  for (size_t i = 0; i != idx.size(); ++i) idx[i] = i;

  // sort indexes based on comparing values in v
  sort(idx.begin(), idx.end(),
       [&v](size_t i1, size_t i2)
       {
         return v[i1] >= v[i2];
       });

  return idx;
}
```

2.Then I did a function which will sort first and a second vector using the third one.To achieve it I had to create temporary vectors one for a first vector, one for a second, and **two** for the last one.

*Why **two**?*
Because I have to remember the sorted indexes of the third vector and I need a one temporary to which I will be pushing elements of the original third vector according to sorted indexes.

```
 void SortByIndexes(vector<int>& Pi,vector<int> &Wi,vector<int>& PidivWi)
    {

      vector<int> Pitemp, Witemp, PidivWitemp,SortedIndexes;

      for (auto i : sort_indexes(PidivWi))
      {

        SortedIndexes.push_back(i);

      }

     for (auto i : SortedIndexes)
      {
        Pitemp.push_back(Pi[i]);
        Witemp.push_back(Wi[i]);
        PidivWitemp.push_back(PidivWi[i]);
      }

      swap(Pi, Pitemp);
      swap(Wi, Witemp);
      swap(PidivWi,PidivWitemp);

    }
```

3. After sorting just swap sorted vectors with original ones.
Done.

**Thank you all guys.**

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the way to go (and would have been my answer in case it would lack).