# specifying arguments to the compare function in C++ sort

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, stl

My question is how the compare function in the C++ sort function takes parameters. 
if I want to sort an array but also want to preserve the index of the elements i thought of sorting the index array based on the elements in the actual array. The issue is i am not able to find how to pass the parameters to the compare function.
suppose the array is 3 5 4 2 indexes are 0 1 2 3 . I want the index array output 3 0 2 1 which is 2 3 4 5 . how can i do that using the sort function.

Comment: The comparator passed to `std::sort` doesn't have to be a function - it can also be an object of a class with overloaded `operator()`. This object can maintain state. A lambda expression is a common way to manufacture this object.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/12399290/10990718

Comment: thanks a lot for the link. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it :

```
vector<int> data{  3, 5, 4, 2 },
            index{ 0, 1, 2, 3 };
sort(index.begin(), index.end(), [&data](int i, int j) { return data[i] < data[j]; });
for (int i : index)
{
    cout << i << ' ';
}
```

Comment: In case you don't know what he's doing [&data](int i, int j) is a lambda function, you can think of it like 1 instance of a simple inline.

Comment: If a lambda compare wasn't available, then a vector of pointers could be used, `vector<int *>ptr{&data[0], &data[1], &data[2], &data[3]};`. The compare function input would be two `int *`. To convert ptr to index: `index[i] = ptr[i] - &data[0];` .