# c++ finding the argsort of a vector<float>

Tags: c++, sorting, indices

Following [C++ sorting and keeping track of indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577475/c-sorting-and-keeping-track-of-indexes) :
This is how to get the `argsort` of `vector<int> v`

```cpp
vector<int> VectorArgSort(vector<int> &v) {
    /* Get the indices that gives a sorted vector v*/

    vector<int> retIndices(v.size());
    iota(retIndices.begin(), retIndices.end(), 0);

    stable_sort(
        retIndices.begin(), retIndices.end(),
        [&v](int i1, int i2) {return v[i1] < v[i2];});

    return retIndices;
}
```

But what i want is to have `vector<int> VectorArgSort(vector<float> &v)` that still gives vector because they are indices, but to perform it on `vector<float> &v` instead.

I tried changing several of the defined `int` types to doubles, but i dont think i should because they all points towards the indices. So im not sure how to change the function to get what i want.

Comment: Please show the error message then.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to change the `vector<int>` to `vector<float>` in the argument of the function.

```
vector<int> VectorArgSort(vector<float> &v) {
```

see working version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ccabdbb9e70481fd)