# C++ vector sorting and mapping from unsorted to sorted elements

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, indexing

I have to perform the following task. Take a `std::vector<float>`, sort the elements in descending order and have an indexing that maps the unsorted elements to the sorted ones. Please note that *the order really matters*: I need a map that, given the i-th element in the unsorted vector, tells me where this element is found in the sorted one. The vice-versa has been achieved already in a pretty smart way (through c++ lambdas) e.g., here: [C++ sorting and keeping track of indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577475/c-sorting-and-keeping-track-of-indexes). Nevertheless, I was not able to find an equally smart way to perform the "inverse" task. I would like to find a fast way, since this kind of mapping has to be performed many times and the vector has big size.
Please find in the following a simple example of what I need to achieve and my (probably suboptimal, since it relies on `std::find`) solution of the problem. Is it the most fast/efficient way to perform this task? If not, are there better solutions?

### Example

Starting vector: `v = {4.5, 1.2, 3.4, 2.3}`

Sorted vector: `v_s = {4.5, 3.4, 2.3, 1.2}`

What I **do want**: `map = {0, 3, 1, 2}`

What I **do not want**: `map = {0, 2, 3, 1}`

### My solution

```
template <typename A> std::vector<size_t> get_indices(std::vector<A> & v_unsorted, std::vector<A> & v_sorted) {
  std::vector<size_t> idx;
  for (auto const & element : v_unsorted) {
    typename std::vector<A>::iterator itr = std::find(v_sorted.begin(), v_sorted.end(), element);
      idx.push_back(std::distance(v_sorted.begin(), itr));
  }
  return idx;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your time, cheers!

Comment: If you want help improving working code, you should post this on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you do decide to do so, please delete the question here.

Comment: possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577475/c-sorting-and-keeping-track-of-indexes

Comment: It is not clear to me what question is being asked here.  Are you asking how to make your code "equally smart"?

Comment: Hi @NathanOliver, as I pointed out in the main body of the question, actually this is not a duplicate. That answer targets a similar (but slightly different) problem. It provides the mapping of sorted elements to unsorted elements, while I want to achieve the opposite: mapping of unsorted elements to sorted elements.

Comment: Hi @DrewDormann, thanks for your comment, I slightly edited my question. I believe my solution is suboptimal in terms of speed since it relies on repeated usage of std::find. I am asking if there are better solutions the problem

Comment: @FabioIemmi in that case, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) is the correct place to ask.  Questions along the lines of "What would be better than this?" invite opinions.

Comment: @DrewDormann No, code review is not for things like that.

Comment: Apply the algorithm shown in the linked answer to your array of doubles, and then apply it again to the resulting array of indices (with the sense of comparison reversed).

Comment: @FabioIemmi -- Also note that this is templated on type `A`, swapping elements of `A` may be time-consuming, too big, or in come cases, `A` cannot be swapped due to it not being copyable (maybe the copy operations on `A` are marked as `= delete;`).  Thus the solutions using an index array are the better, if not best way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code below.

**My version of `get_indices` does the following:**

1. Create a vector of indices mapping **sorted -> unsorted**, using code similar to the one in the link you mentioned in your post ([C++ sorting and keeping track of indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577475/c-sorting-and-keeping-track-of-indexes)).
2. Then by traversing those indices once, create the sorted vector, and the final indices mapping **unsorted -> sorted**.

The complexity is **O(n * log(n))**, since the sort is done in O(n * log(n)), and the final traversal is linear.

**The code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

template <typename T>
std::vector<size_t> get_indices(std::vector<T> const & v_unsorted, std::vector<T> & v_sorted) 
{
    std::vector<size_t> idx_sorted2unsorted(v_unsorted.size()); 
    std::iota(idx_sorted2unsorted.begin(), idx_sorted2unsorted.end(), 0);

    // Create indices mapping (sorted -> unsorted) sorting in descending order:
    std::stable_sort(idx_sorted2unsorted.begin(), idx_sorted2unsorted.end(),
        [&v_unsorted](size_t i1, size_t i2) 
            { return v_unsorted[i1] > v_unsorted[i2]; }); // You can use '<' for ascending order

    // Create final indices (unsorted -> sorted) and sorted array:
    std::vector<size_t> idx_unsorted2sorted(v_unsorted.size());
    v_sorted.resize(v_unsorted.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v_unsorted.size(); ++i)
    {
        idx_unsorted2sorted[idx_sorted2unsorted[i]] = i;
        v_sorted[i] = v_unsorted[idx_sorted2unsorted[i]];
    }
    return idx_unsorted2sorted;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<double> v_unsorted{ 4.5, 1.2, 3.4, 2.3 };
    std::vector<double> v_sorted;
    std::vector<size_t> idx_unsorted2sorted = get_indices(v_unsorted, v_sorted);
    for (auto const & i : idx_unsorted2sorted)
    {
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
0, 3, 1, 2,
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the mapping from sorted to unsorted indices, you only need a loop to invert it.

I am building on the code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12399290/4117728. It provides a function to get the vector you do not want:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <vector>
> #include <numeric>      // std::iota
> #include <algorithm>    // std::sort, std::stable_sort
>
> using namespace std;
>
> template <typename T>
> vector<size_t> sort_indexes(const vector<T> &v) {
>
>   // initialize original index locations
>   vector<size_t> idx(v.size());
>   iota(idx.begin(), idx.end(), 0);
>
>   // sort indexes based on comparing values in v
>   // using std::stable_sort instead of std::sort
>   // to avoid unnecessary index re-orderings
>   // when v contains elements of equal values 
>   stable_sort(idx.begin(), idx.end(),
>        [&v](size_t i1, size_t i2) {return v[i1] < v[i2];});
>
>   return idx;
> }
> ```

Sorting the vector is `O(N logN)` your code calls `find` N times resulting in `O(N*N)`. On the other hand, adding a single loop is only linear, hence sorting plus the loop is still `O(N log N)`.

```
int main() {
    std::vector<double> unsorted{4.5, 1.2, 3.4, 2.3};
    auto idx = sort_indexes(unsorted);
    for (auto i : idx) std::cout << unsorted[i] << "\n";
    
    // the vector you do not want
    for (auto i : idx) std::cout << i << "\n";
    
    // invert it
    std::vector<size_t> idx_inverse(idx.size());
    for (size_t i=0;i<idx.size();++i) idx_inverse[ idx[i] ] = i;
    
    // the vector you do want
    for (auto i : idx_inverse) std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K5Pzn7Y96)