# Is there a way to find duplicates effectively?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to find duplicates even though they have been put in by user input. I've tried a few methods, for loop to do the checks but that doesnt work.
Anyone got any idea how I might be able to do this effectively?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int size, * array; 
    std::cout << "Indtast arrayet's stoerrelse." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> size; // optager input til størrelse af arrayet fra brugeren
    array = new int[size]; // dynamisk allokeret array

    while (size >= 100) { // while loop til at tjekke om arrayets størrelse er for stort
        std::cout << "Forkert input af array." << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    while (size <= 100) { // while loop til når arrayet er af rigtig størrelse

        float sum = 0;
        float gns = 0;

        std::cout << "Tast op til " << size << " vaerdier ind." << std::endl; 

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { // for loop til at optage input til hver element i arrayen
            std::cout << "Indtast vaerdi for array-nr: " << i << std::endl;
            std::cin >> array[i]; // optager input til hvert element

            sum += array[i]; // finder summen af elementerne i arrayet
        }
        std::cout << "Min-vaerdi er: " << *std::min_element(array, array + size) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Max-vaerdi er: " << *std::max_element(array, array + size) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Summen er: " << sum << std::endl;
        gns = sum / size; // udregner gennemsnittet 
        std::cout << "Gennemsnittet er: " << gns << std::endl;


        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: sort it, then duplicates will be adjacent.

Comment: Or put the input in a `set` and all the duplicates will be gone automatically.

Comment: Use a different data structure.

Comment: `while(size <= 100) { ...; return 0; }` ... that looks off. It looks like `while (size <= 100) ` should have been `else` and `while (size >= 100)` should have been `if (size >= 100)`

Comment: *Is there a way to find duplicates effectively?* -- `std::sort`, and then if you want to find where they are, [std::adjacent_find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find).

Comment: `I'm trying to find duplicates` is not full description of problem which this code suppose to solve (everything else is just complains it doesn't work). Also string literals and comments are not in English so it is hard decipher what this suppose to do. Please provide better description and example of input and output (unit test are best in that). Please read [ask].

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the nature of the `while`.

Comment: That code makes no attempt to find duplicates. Why is it relevant to your question?

Comment: _"I'm trying to find duplicates..."_ - Since there's no effort made to find them in your current code, what will you do once you find a duplicate? Just remove it?

Comment: I tried using for loops to find the duplicates, I since removed those lines of code. a for loop for i and j+1

Comment: @VIGGO420 Ok ... and... what will you do once you find a duplicate? Remove/exclude it from the mean value calculation?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Just display it with cout

Comment: Please consider using https://codereview.stackexchange.com as this is not safe nor modern C++ and the community will be able to help you improve your code.  Generally, for example, you should not be using "new". Read up on the STL and especially std::set.  Also there is a mixture of integral and floating point data types, which looks wrong.

Comment: Ok, so it should still be included in the mean value calculation? Oh, well, then do what's suggested. `std::sort` the array and then `std::adjacent_find` the duplicates. Don't use `new[]`/`delete[]`  though. Use a `std::vector<int> array(size);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modern (C++20) approach using ranges. As suggested in the comments, you should sort your vector and then use `adjacent_if`. It is always recommended to use the algorithms from the standard library than to try to re-implement common stuff like this yourself using basic procedural tools like for and while loops.

This approach would work with an array as well, but I suggest using an `std::vector`.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

void print(std::vector<int> const& v){
    // print the vector
    for (auto const& i: v){
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4};

    std::cout << "Input vector = \t\t";
    print(v);

    // sort the vector
    std::ranges::sort(v);

    std::cout << "Sorted vector = \t";
    print(v);

    // find duplicates and print them
    auto it = std::ranges::adjacent_find(v);
    while (it != v.end()){
        std::cout 
            << "Duplicates start at v[" 
            << std::distance(v.begin(), it)
            << "] = "
            << *it
            << "\n";
        it = std::ranges::adjacent_find(it, v.end(), std::ranges::not_equal_to());
        it = std::ranges::adjacent_find(it, v.end());
    }
    for (; it != v.end(); ++it){
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }

    // remove duplicates    
    auto ret = std::ranges::unique(v);
    v.erase(ret.begin(), ret.end());

    std::cout << "No duplicates = \t";
    print(v);
    

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Input vector =      1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 
Sorted vector =     1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
Duplicates start at v[0] = 1
Duplicates start at v[4] = 3
Duplicates start at v[7] = 4
No duplicates =     1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
```

Try it on compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/YP3zb7PYf

Comment: In case you want to know the indices of the duplicates in your unsorted input array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577475/c-sorting-and-keeping-track-of-indexes